# Getting [ErrorException] - installing yii2 using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2

I am trying to install Yii2 on WAMP using composer.

```
c:\Users\username>php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0
```

I am getting the following error when I run the command which is given above.

> [ErrorException]
>   Argument 1 passed to Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\BowerRepository::createVcsRepositoryConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository.php  on line 136 and defined

Can someone help solving this error? But, it is created a folder named "basic".

I have copied this folder to `D:\wamp\www` and when I access `localhost/basic/web/` from browser, I am getting the following error.

> ReflectionException
>   Class yii\debug\Module does not exist

I am following the instructions to install yii2 from http://www.yiiframework.com/download/

Please assist me to resolve these issues.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run app creation without specifying the version? `php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic`

Comment: have you tried updating composer via `composer self-update`? and have you added the composer plugin specified in the Yii installation instructions?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it without specifying the version and used composer self-update also. I still see the same error. I have already run the command
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta3"
before creating basic app of yii2

Comment: Hi, I tried installing it by downloading basic template archive file from the url [yiiframework](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/) as an alternative method of installing yii2. It is working now. But, I am wondering how to resolve the error if I use composer to install yii2.

Comment: what is your wamp version?beacuse if you don't use the version 2.5 the composser not work

Answer (score 1):

First windows does not have a curl processor like unix so you need to use the other option for installing Composer

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

For this to work you need the php.exe processor to be on your path, so you have 2 options here. Either add the c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z folder to your PATH or my prefered option write yourself a little .cmd file which will do it for you like this

```
addphp.cmd
PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z
```

Put this file in a folder already registered on your path so you can run it from anywhere in a command window.

Now you will have to edit the \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini file. This is similiar to the one used by php code run through the Apache web server but is only used by the PHP CLI (Command Line Interpreter)

Make sure the extension php_curl is uncommented or the above line wont work i.e. remove the ; comment symbol

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

So now run a command window, cd into the folder that you want composer installed into and run the command above, then follow the rest of the install instructions on [Install instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Thank you for reminding me.

This error happens because of invalid json on plugin you or application requested (npm or bower).

The link [here](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/pull/133) suggests you to run:

`composer global update`.

This will update composer cache. Hope it helps.